# How to find month from number of days and year in R?

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame like this:

```
day<-c(61,63,91)
year<-c(2000,2000,2001)
df<-data.frame(year,day)  
df
  year day
1 2000  61
2 2000  63
3 2001  91
```

where 'day' is the number of day in that year. So the first row is 61st day in year 2000. I want to add month too. So required output:

```
  year day month
1 2000  61 3
2 2000  63 3
3 2001  91 4
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df$month <- with(df, strptime(paste(year, day), format="%Y %j")$mon+1)
df$month
#[1] 3 3 4
```

Comment: Wonder why you need to do the `+1`. Why the `mon` gives the previous month? `with(df, format(strptime(paste(year, day), format="%Y %j"), "%m"))` makes more sense to me

Comment: @David Arenburg.  I tried a similar one previously (edited that), but I had to convert it back from `character`.  I can't find the link for the cause, but I read somewhere recently that `strptime` starts from `0`. For example `strptime("2000-12-01", format="%Y-%m-%d")$mon
#[1] 11;  strptime("2000-01-01", format="%Y-%m-%d")$mon#[1] 0`